# How can I find the images in my Lightroom catalog that don't yet have smart previews?

Tags: lightroom

I have hundreds of images that weren't able to build a smart preview since the drive that was containing my Lightroom smart previews ran out of space. I would like to know how to find those images that don't have a smart preview. How can I do so? Thanks!

Comment: If you follow the [steps in the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/lightroom-smart-previews.html) are you able to build smart previews? Can you perhaps edit your answer to indicate what you've looked into so far, such that people don't suggest things you've tried/read already?

Comment: But I don't know which images had a smart preview built and which didn't, so I can't just manually select the images and then make Lightroom build a smart preview. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find photos without a smart preview by using a smart collection.

Go to **Library → New Smart Collection...** and add a condition **Has Smart Preview is false**:

[image]

This gets you the photos that do not have a smart preview.

Then you can follow the [steps from the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/lightroom-smart-previews.html#CreateSmartPreviews) to create smart previews on the fly.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I already know how to create a smart preview for a particular image that I know doesn't have smart previews, but I didn't know about smart collections. Thanks!

Comment: Also, your technique allowed me to find out that I had over 5,500 images that didn't build a smart preview. I previously thought that they also had smart previews. By the way, I actually have a catalog of about 5,700 images. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Do check if you actually need the smart preview, perhaps a regular preview is sufficient. You can Google around to see what pros and cons are.

Comment: Hmm, that's not a good use of smart previews. If you have really important images you need a back-up. There is no way around that. Smart previews might become corrupted, are low quality (as you already noticed) and are only readable by Lightroom. If you lose your images, you do not want to depend on a commercial software package like LR to be able to restore images. Storage is relatively cheap (depending on where in the world you are). I would like to urge you to consider a real backup.